# Generic term for limb armor

Tags: anatomy, armors, terminology

Is there a generic term that encompasses the various types of limb armor together?

I'm hoping there's a catch-all I don't know about that I could use that would describe the collective of bracers/greaves/pauldrons/etc.

Comment: "The armor on the arms and legs"?

Comment: Is this a world building question or just a vocabulary one? If we had some context, we could phrase it in terms of world building.

Comment: You mean vambraces, not bracers. A bracer is a special arm covering used by archers to keep the bowstring from damaging their inner forearm, while a vambrace is the part of a suit of medieval armor covering the part of the arm from the bottom of the pauldron down to the wrist (directly equivalent to greaves, which go from the cuisses (armor that covers the thighs) down to the sabatons (armor that covers the feet)).

Comment: You might want to repost this on english.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I think many of the answers are trying to focus on human-based armors. Your question is generic enough to imply non-human anatomy needing to be armored. Is that what you're trying to get at?

Comment: "limb armor" is the closest you have, there is no reason to have a more specific term for such an odd idea, specific parts of armor have specific terms but there is no terms for say helms and gauntlets and excluding everything else, why would there be?

Answer (score 8):

Greaves are armor for the lower legs, not armor for the arms. Just use the terms Upper Canon and Lower Canon as generic terms for armor on the arms.

From http://medieval.stormthecastle.com/all-about-medieval-armor.htm:

> Plate armor for the arms came into use during this century and this piece of armor was called vambraces and it was composed of armor for the upper arm called the upper canon and armor for the lower arm called the lower canon.

Comment: I had never heard the terms Upper Canon and Lower Canon used for anything.  But google and sure enough.  Text and link added for others who like me are skeptical despite being ignorant.

Comment: I'm looking for a term that works for arms and legs, ideally.  I'm aware that greaves are for legs.

Comment: Armor, or just armor plus a body part. Using generic terms for armor makes you seem to  have no real knowledge about the subject you are writing about.

Comment: Isn't this a "there is no answer" answer? The OP's Q shows they know there are terms for specific spots. This seems to be listing more of what they don't want?

Answer (score 6):

You could just go with "peripheral armour", but really, the sticky-out-bits on humans tend to be specialised for their tasks and the armour they require is going to be quite different.

There's a reason that we have different words for "things that keep your toes warm" and "things that keep your hands warm", rather than "sticky out cold bit covers". (and before anyone says that you could use "thermals" to refer to coverings for the top half or bottom half of the body, note that this is as helpful as saying that you can use "armour" to refer to coverings for the arms and legs, too)

Comment: Because *phalanges* is a silly sounding word.

Comment: @Mazura because the assembly made from them is _different_ for the bits that stick out of  _back_ end of a human than those that stick out of the _front_ end of a human and indeed a wide variety of other tetrapods too.

Comment: @StarfishPrime: (Upvoted.) English is unusual in that it has different words for the digits of the front/upper autopodium (= the hand or manus) and the digits of the hind/lower autopodium (= the foot or the pes). (And even in English, the thing made of phalanges can be called a digit when the distinction between a finger and a toe is not important.)

Comment: @AlexP the thing it is attached to doesn't get a general term though, surely? I can't be certain of course, but I'd be very surprised if any language that was evolved by a tool-using biped ended up with the same term to mean hand and foot.

Comment: @StarfishPrime: In anatomy we have the word [autopodium](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/autopodium), for use when we don't care whether we are speaking of the forelimbs or the hindlimbs. (And English, just like French "patte" or German "Pfote" or Romanian "labă", has the word "paw" to refer to the autopodia of a non-human animal without distinction between the forelegs and the hindlegs.)

Comment: @AlexP eh, the difference between fore- and hindpaws was probably less interesting than the distinction between hands capable of grasping and feet that were not. Looks like "foot" and "paw" might have similar origins, maybe. Autopodium sounds suspiciously like a more modern construction, but I don't have access to any kind of etymology reference worthy of the name :-(

Comment: *"Sounds suspiciously like a more modern construction:* well, comparative anatomy did not exist at all before the 18th century, so, obviously. The word itself may be older, like many words used in science; [here is the word *autopodia*](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_3eUk9OUemvIC/page/n121/mode/1up) in Giuseppe Laurenzi's *Amalthea onomastica*, 1708, glossed as *"iter non equo, sed propriis pedibus factum"*, "a journey made not on horseback but on one's own feet". But by the 19th century it was well-established in anatomy with its current meaning, the distal part of the limbs of tetrapods.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that the term is simply "extremities".

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extremity):
"Definition of extremity...
b: a limb of the body
especially : a human hand or foot"

So, if your armor is just a kind (not a full-on powered suit, just some conventional armor) that covers these places, why not call them "extremities"?